# mysql and php database error

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database, `Employee_info(stores all employee information )` and `Job_Info(store all job title , job description)`.The code inserts the data with no problems but when updating this error is printed on the browser :

`"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Employee_database.job_info, CONSTRAINT job_info_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY (Employee_Id) REFERENCES Employee_info (Employee_Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE)"`.

What could be the problem ? Here is the code

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Employee_info` WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'";
      $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
         $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
   if ($resultcount > 0) 
 {
  mysql_query("UPDATE  `employee_info` SET `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name',

                                         `Physical_Address` = '$P_Address',

                                         `Phone_Number` = '$Phone',

                                         `Email_Address` = '$E_Address'
             WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'"
           )
    or die(mysql_error());
    }
                  else {
                          $sql="INSERT INTO employee_info
                                 (
                             Name_Of_Employee,
                             Physical_Address,
                             Phone_Number,
                             Email_Address
                         )
                     VALUES (
                        '$Name',
                        '$P_Address',
                        '$Phone',
                        '$E_Address'
                                 );
                          if(!mysql_query($sql))
                           {    
                         die('cannot store in employee_info'.mysql_error());
                           }
}

$Employee_Id=mysql_insert_id();
 $qry = "SELECT * FROM `Job_info` WHERE `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title'";
  $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
       $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
     if ($resultcount > 0) {
                        "UPDATE `Job_info` SET `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id' ,
                               `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title',
                               `Job_Description` = '$Job_Description'

                             WHERE `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id'")
                         or die(mysql_error());
}
else 
{
$sql="INSERT INTO ad_info (
                       Employee_Id,
                       Job_Title,
                       Job_Description
                       )
                    VALUES (
                       '$Employee_Id',
                       '$Job_Title',
                       '$Job_Description'
                       )";
                       if(!mysql_query($sql))
                       {
                       die('cannot store in job info'.mysql_error());}
                       }
```

here is the databse design

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Employee_Id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name_Of_Employee | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Physical_Address | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Phone_Number     | int(14)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Email_address    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |                             |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| jOB_Id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Employee_Id      | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Job_Title        | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Job_Description  | text(100)   | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: For future users seeing your questions. If you know this, great! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @njk You beat me by just a few seconds.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I think both are valuable.

Comment: Problem 1: `mysql_xxx()` funcs are deprecated. Beware of using them. Recommend switching to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Problem 2: Cannot tell whether you are escaping your SQL variables. If not, then you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Problem 3: The error you are getting is related to the DB table design, but you haven't shown us that table design. We cannot give accurate help without seeing that.

Comment: try any decent ide(NetBeean could be good option) which tell you syntax error http://i.stack.imgur.com/MPFAO.png

Comment: @NullPointer What happened to using good old fashioned Notepad?

Comment: @njk i never used that .. but there will be no problem if it tell syntax error while typing

Comment: @NullPointer Well that's sort of my point. I learned on Notepad which doesn't do any sort of syntax highlighting. Teaches you to form proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what your error is telling you.

You **cannot add or update a child row** because of a constraint that exists. This means that updates are restricted, or the key does not exist. If it's the latter, you must first create that key in the referenced table.

If you don't switch over to `mysqli_` or `PDO` and use prepared statements, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Echo your `$sql` statement. 99% sure you will see your error. You obviously have an error in what you are trying to put in your table and how it relates to the constraint on your foreign key.

IE, your FK wants a number 1-10 and you are trying to put in an 11.